# FFTW advanced layout -- inembed=n and inembed=NULL give different results?

Tags: c++, c, fft, fftw

I'm working with batched 2D FFTs using the FFTW advanced data layout API.

According to the [FFTW Advanced Complex DFT](http://cluster.earlham.edu/bccd-ng/testing/mobeen/GALAXSEEHPC/fftw-3.3/doc/html/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html) documentation:

> Passing **NULL** for an nembed parameter is equivalent to passing **n**.

However, I'm getting different results when using `inembed = onembed = NULL` vs. `inembed = onembed = n`. **What could be causing the results not to  match?**

---

Let's do an example...

**Setup**

```
int howMany = 2;
int nRows = 4;
int nCols = 4;
int n[2] = {nRows, nCols};
float* h_in = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * nRows*nCols*howMany);
for(int i=0; i<(nRows*nCols*howMany); i++){ //initialize h_in to [0 1 2 3 4 ...]
    h_in[i] = (float)i;
    printf("h_in[%d] = %f \n", i, h_in[i]);
}
```

**FFTW Plan** using `inembed == onembed == NULL`

```
fftwf_plan forwardPlan = fftwf_plan_many_dft_r2c(2, //rank
                            n, //dimensions = {nRows, nCols}
                            howMany, //howmany
                            h_in, //in
                            NULL, //inembed
                            howMany, //istride
                            1, //idist
                            h_freq, //out
                            NULL, //onembed
                            howMany, //ostride
                            1, //odist
                            FFTW_PATIENT /*flags*/);
```

I also ran a version of this with `inembed = onembed = n = {nRows, nCols}`.

---

### Results

Notice that using `NULL` or `n` gives the same numerical results, but **in a different order in memory**:

**Version 1: `inembed == onembed == NULL`**

```
result[0][0,1] = 240, 0 
result[1][0,1] = 256, 0 
result[2][0,1] = -16, 16 
result[3][0,1] = -16, 16 
result[4][0,1] = -16, 0 
result[5][0,1] = -16, 0  //this line and above match the other version
result[6][0,1] = -64, 64  //this line and below don't match (data is in a different order)
result[7][0,1] = -64, 64  
result[8][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[9][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[10][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[11][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[12][0,1] = -64, 0 
result[13][0,1] = -64, 0 
result[14][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[15][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[16][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[17][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[18][0,1] = -64, -64 
result[19][0,1] = -64, -64 
result[20][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[21][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[22][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[23][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[24][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[25][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[26][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[27][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[28][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[29][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[30][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[31][0,1] = 0, 0
```

**Version 2: `inembed = onembed = n = {nRows, nCols}`**

```
result[0][0,1] = 240, 0 
result[1][0,1] = 256, 0 
result[2][0,1] = -16, 16 
result[3][0,1] = -16, 16 
result[4][0,1] = -16, 0 
result[5][0,1] = -16, 0 
result[6][0,1] = 0, 0  
result[7][0,1] = 0, 0  
result[8][0,1] = -64, 64 
result[9][0,1] = -64, 64 
result[10][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[11][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[12][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[13][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[14][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[15][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[16][0,1] = -64, 0 
result[17][0,1] = -64, 0 
result[18][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[19][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[20][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[21][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[22][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[23][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[24][0,1] = -64, -64 
result[25][0,1] = -64, -64 
result[26][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[27][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[28][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[29][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[30][0,1] = 0, 0 
result[31][0,1] = 0, 0
```

---

Here's a [working implementation of this experiment](https://github.com/forresti/stackoverflow_examples/tree/master/cufft_fftw_batched/fftw_experiments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:** 
The out-of-place example with `embed != NULL` in the above example is solved by setting `inembed = {nRows, nCols}` and `onembed = {nRows, (nCols/2 + 1)}`.

---

**Details:**

I resolved this after **very** carefully reading the FFTW documentation and getting some help from [Matteo Frigo](http://www.fftw.org/~athena/). You can retrace my steps here:

According to [4.4.2 Advanced Real-data DFTs](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs.html#Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs) in the FFTW manual: `If an nembed parameter is NULL, it is interpreted as what it would be in the basic interface.`

Let's assume our input real data is of dimension `nx * ny`.
For the FFTW basic interface, [2.4 Multi-Dimensional DFTs of Real Data](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html) explains the following `inembed` and `onembed` conventions for 2D real-to-complex FFTs:

```
if out-of-place:
    inembed = [ny, nx]
    onembed = [ny, (nx/2 + 1)]

if in-place:
    inembed = [ny, 2(nx/2 + 1)]
    onembed = [ny, (nx/2 + 1)]
```

So, when we use the simple FFTW `r2c` interface  or use the advanced interface with `embed=NULL`, FFTW defaults to the above `embed` parameters. We can reproduce the numerical results from `embed=NULL` by using the above `embed` parameters.

---

It turns out that the statement `Passing NULL for an nembed parameter is equivalent to passing n` comes from the [FFTW complex-to-complex](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html) manual page. But, we're doing [real-to-complex transforms](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs.html#Advanced-Real_002ddata-DFTs) in the examples above. Real-to-complex transforms  have a different convention than complex-to-complex transforms for `inembed` and `onembed`.